# Embedded Google Sheet Deletes Elements After It

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-apps-script

I'm looking to embed a Google sheet into a Google Chrome extension. My code is as follows:

```
<html>
  <iframe
    src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQhhQM1ag9M_exkDEV8omFWuI5-4tRizOZ5pl0ZzxpAEJ3rHfWzWilEzjgV4jwpyEj2aaTUkfQx6DRK/pubhtml?gid=1478993491&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false"
  </iframe>
  <p>Hello, World!</p>
</html>
```

For some reason, "Hello, World!" not only doesn't show up visually (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfgrY.jpg), but isn't there when I inspect elements (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf21n.jpg). What is going on? How can I fix it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close the opening tag with the `>` sign. This should work

```html
<html>
  <iframe
    src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQhhQM1ag9M_exkDEV8omFWuI5-4tRizOZ5pl0ZzxpAEJ3rHfWzWilEzjgV4jwpyEj2aaTUkfQx6DRK/pubhtml?gid=1478993491&amp;single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false">
  </iframe>
  <p>Hello, World!</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Well the src attribute was quite long and you probably got lost in all those characters :p It happens @reisnern21